# What is the cause of apparent anticorrelation between a good metallic conductor and its superconductivity property?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, superconductivity, phase-transition

Excellent metallic conductors (elements) such as gold, silver, copper etc do not easily become superconductors (unless cooled at extremely low temperatures, perhaps). But often comparatively poor metallic conductors (elements) such as Hg, Nb, La, Pb etc. easily exhibit superconductivity in the sense that they have a relatively high $T_c$. What is the cause of this apparent anticorrelation?

Answer (score 2):

Charge carriers in superconductors are Cooper pairs. A Cooper pair is a bound state of two electrons with $\vec{k}$ and $-\vec{k}$ and opposite spins. This bound state is formed by exchanging a phonon. When a metal like Nb is a poor conductor at room temperature in means there's a strong interaction between its electrons and phonons, therefore, it'll be a potential superconductor at low temperatures. However, very good conductors like cu or Au have very weK electron-phonon interaction therefore they never become superconductors at even very low temperatures.

Hope this was helpful. Cheers!

Comment: Ok. But what determines the strength of the interaction between electrons and phonons?

Comment: Generally, the mean free path of electrons in the conductor determines the strength.

Comment: This is what I understand for your comment. Excellent conductors seem to have a shorter mean free path compared to conductors that are inferior i.e. the frequency of electron-phonon scattering is smaller. This feature is largely responsible for why excellent conductors are so difficult to display superconductivity. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, except that good conductors have a longer mean free path, therefore, they don't get scattered as much at room temperature.

Comment: Sorry, longer. You're right.